# Integral with log of absolute value of sine

Tags: definite-integrals, complex-integration, trigonometric-integrals

Show that
$$\int_{-\pi/3}^{\pi/3} \log \vert 8 \sin(t/2) (1 + \sin t)^2 \vert dt = 0.$$

WolframAlpha claims that this is true. I've tried manipulating the integrand a bunch and various trig identities, but it hasn't simplified things. It looks vaguely like Jensen's formula, but I'm not sure how to use this.

It also sort of looks like one of those integrals that can be evaluated using complex analysis and contour shifting, but I don't see how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that (using $t \to -t$ on the negative interval):

$\int_{-\pi/3}^{\pi/3} \log \vert 8 \sin(t/2) (1 + \sin t)^2 \vert dt =2\pi \log 2+2\int_{0}^{\pi/3}\log {\sin(t/2)}dt+ 4\int_{0}^{\pi/3}\log {\cos t}dt$

Using now $t/2 \to t$ we get

$\int_{0}^{\pi/3}\log {\sin(t/2)}dt=2\int_{0}^{\pi/6}\log {\sin t}dt=2\int_{\pi/3}^{\pi/2}\log {\cos t}dt$,

so putting all together the original integral becomes:

$2\pi \log 2+4\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\log {\cos t}dt=4\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\log {(2\cos t)}dt=0$ by the well known result (and easy to prove by simple manipulations once one argues that the integral is indeed convergent) that

$\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\log {(2\sin t)}dt=\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\log {(2\cos t)}dt=0$

Comment: It looks like in the first step you are claiming that $$\int_{-\pi/3}^{\pi/3} \log \vert 1 + \sin t \vert dt = 2\int_{0}^{\pi/3} \log \cos t dt$$ Why is that?

Comment: no - by changing variables $t \to -t$), the lower integral becomes $\int_{0}^{\pi/3} \log \vert 1 - \sin t \vert dt$, ($\sin$ is odd!) so when you add (hence multiply the logarithm arguments) you get $1-\sin^2=\cos^2$; taking the logarithm pushes the $2$ in front.

Comment: Sorry, it should have been yes above - the integral between opposite values works as noted, thought the comment was about the integral from zero